# Jenkinsfile. I want to use objects. How to run shell script from method of object?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sh

In "commons" pipelines we can use sh(script...), but I want to use objects to map containars.
But inside methods of object it is not possible to use sh(script...) - Jenkins throwing groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.
I try many tricks, but all finished the same...

Here is part of exemplary Jenkinsfile. In Container.run() method I need to run script.

```
class Container {

    def run( containerName ) {
        //sh(script: "docker start ${containerName}")
    } 

}

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        HUB_CONTAINER_NAME = 'hub'
    }

    
    stages {
        stage('Running container') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def container = new Container( HUB_CONTAINER_NAME )
                    hubContainer.run( )
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be extremely difficult for anyone to answer this question because you haven't provided any sample code.  For better results update your question to include your Jenkinsfile code and maybe some pseudo demonstrating what you need to accomplish

Comment: `to use objects to map containars` What objects to what containers? What do you mean by "map"? `But inside methods of object` What objects? What methods? Inside what exactly? What is the exact error message _with_ the full verbatim tracestack including all the other logs? And, why not just toss groovy and do `sh "docker run ..."`? My experience with jenkins and groovy has been very very bad, we just use scripts, which we can test locally. Are you building some start-or-run docker service runner? Did you consider using `docker compose` or an orchestrator?

Comment: OK. I've added Jenkinsfile code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass that this global object. Typically, they call it `script` in plugins. TBH I do not understand it much, sometimes it is passed implicit, sometimes resolved globally, sometimes not. Usually it passed to the class constructor to have a reference at all times when needed.

```
class Container {
    def run(script, containerName) {
        script.sh("docker start ${containerName}")
    } 
}
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Running container') {
            steps {
                script {
                    new Container().run(this, "thename")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Example from docker jenkins plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/dc3cf1327f1b8c9967a56aa0e1a1f3f0ff79b57c/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy#L33 . or see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ at:

```
class Utilities {
  static def mvn(script, args) {
    script.sh "${script.tool 'Maven'}/bin/mvn -s ${script.env.HOME}/jenkins.xml -o ${args}"
  }
}
```